# After importing module, There isn't module in sys.modules even though method is called in that module

Tags: python

I am practicing package and module using python.

I made five files.

```
C:/doit/game/__init__.py

C:/doit/game/sound/__init__.py

C:/doit/game/sound/echo.py

C:/doit/game/graphic/__init__.py

C:/doit/game/graphic/render.py
```

I enter `from game.sound.echo import *`
and enter `'sys' in sys.modules` to check I am going well and It works.
However, when I enter `'echo' in sys.modules`, it returns False.

Do you know what is something wrong in my case?

Comment: Did you do `from echo import *` or `from game.sound.echo import *`? Why are you trying to find the first one then?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look for the whole module "path" in sys.modules.
Try `'games.sound.echo' in sys.modules`